# undefined variable in Smarty

Tags: php, variables, frameworks, smarty

I'm using DooPHP and I'm generating a security token for my form to protect against csrf attacks. I'm assigning the token to a smarty variable and I can see that it is displayed in the source - so it is available. When I submit the form though, it throws out an error saying:

```
Undefined variable: secToken
See file C:\wamp\www\korysdoo\protected\class\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_data.php
Error on line 291 $x = $$_variable;
```

Any ideas what can be wrong? I can see that the value of secToken is being posted to an appropriate function.

Comment: More information would be helpful in the future. An error message without usage (assigning the variables in php, accessing the variables in the template file, etc) makes it difficult for people to know what could be wrong.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem solved. Though it was lying somewhere else. When the login was unsuccessful (which it was, for different reasons), I was displaying the same login form template without assigning the security token again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [register that variable with smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.tpl#language.assigned.variables) before smarty can make use of it.

You've done that for the template displaying the form, but probably not for the template where you display the submission result. Add it for the result template as well then.

Comment: I am assigning the variable to get it in the submission form. But it doesn't make sense for me to include it in the result template, since it is basically a "Hello, World" template and nothing else. Where would I put it?